How to perform a confirmatory factor analysis
I am trying to perform a confirmatory factor analysis in R based on a data set in data.frame form. For that, I would like to calculate the loading factor (\lambda), the construct reliability (CR) and the average variance extracted (AVE).
My attempt:
model1 <- 'V6 ~ V9'
model1.fit <- sem(model1, data = Datos) 

AVE(model1.fit)

Returns: "named numeric(0)". V6 and V9 are sets of numbers for which I want to calculate the relation V9 implies V6.

Try with sem(as.formula(model1), data = Datos) 

Thank you. It returns something like: "Error in sem.default(as.formula(model1), data = Datos) : missing argument "S" , no value by omission" (translation from Spanish).

According to the sem() function help page, you need to provide a covariance matrix: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sem/versions/3.1-16/topics/sem
